# How to get the position of a element in a Queue

Tags: java, queue

Is there a simpel way to get the current position of a element in a Queue for example:

My current queue is [1,0,5,4,7,8,6]

i want to know the position of the 4 in this queue, in this exampel its 3, is there a way to achieve this with the java queue?

Comment: Queue implements Iterable. `for(DataType dt: queue){ 
doTask(dt) 
}` Where `DataType` can be the DataType of your choice - String etc. and `queue` is your Queue Object.

Comment: Maybe using a `Queue` is the wrong approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already knew that [`queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is a collection that gives us `FIFO` by adding (to the last) and polling (from the head/first).

Which it also means there is no guarantee that you can use it to locate its `index/position` in the queue.

If you really need something like that, instead you can try [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)  to achieve the same effect as follows using `add(E e)` and `remove(0)` and `indexOf(Object o)`:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] arr = new int[]{1,0,5,4,7,8,6};
    for (int a : arr) {
        list.add(a);
    }
    System.out.println("After adding: " + list);
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(4));
    System.out.print("Popping out now: ");
    while(!list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(list.remove(0) + " ");
    }
}
```

And the result will be:

```
After adding: [1, 0, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6]
3 // you can find the index easily;
Popping out now: 1 0 5 4 7 8 6 // still FIFO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Queue may not be the best solution as it doesn't store an index.
However, queue implements [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) so you could iterate over the structure:

```
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(0);
    queue.add(5);
    queue.add(4);
    queue.add(7);
    queue.add(8);
    queue.add(6);

    int lookingFor = 0;

    int counter = 0;
    for (Integer number : queue) {
        if (number == lookingFor) {
            System.out.println(lookingFor + " is at position " + counter + " in the queue.");
            break;
        }
        else counter++;
    }
```

This will output the following:

`0 is at position 1 in the queue.`

Note this will find the first occurrence of 0 only.

Answer (score 1):

The default interface of Queue does not have any methods for this.  If you need this functionality I think you'll have to create your own implementation of the interface using an indexed collection under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

it supports FIFO, and size() you can't have the index of it. You have to count the remove actions on the pile.

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "Value";
Queue<String> queueList= new LinkedList<>();
List listQueue= new ArrayList(queueList);

System.out.println("Index of : " + lista.indexOf("Value"));
```